# insert extra unwanted row to table

Tags: mysql

Why in MYSQL by executing this SQL query 2 rows will add to table? Is this query executes two times!?;

```
INSERT INTO user(`usr_name`, `email`, `name`, `reg_date`, `role_id`)
(
SELECT  "editor1", 
        "editor1@example.com",
        "editor1",
        "2005-12-20",
        2
FROM `user` 
WHERE (("admin", 3) IN (
        SELECT usr_name, role_id
        FROM `user`
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT usr_name, email
        FROM `user`
        WHERE usr_name = "editor1" OR email = "editor1@example.com"
    ))
)
```

result [is here!](http://oi61.tinypic.com/353cz6x.jpg)

Comment: Maybe the `select` statement returns two results? If you could explain a little bit more around this statement, e.g. what you want to achieve and so on, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, two rows in `user` match the `WHERE` conditions.

You are not using the `user` table in the first `FROM`.  So how about this instead:

```
INSERT INTO user(`usr_name`, `email`, `name`, `reg_date`, `role_id`)
    SELECT t.*
    FROM (SELECT 'editor1' as user_name, 'editor1@example.com as email,
                 'editor1' as name, '2005-12-20 as reg_date, 2 as role_id
         ) t
    WHERE ('admin', 3) IN (SELECT usr_name, role_id
                           FROM `user`
                          ) AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT usr_name, email
                      FROM `user` u
                      WHERE u.usr_name = t.usr_name OR u.email = t.email
                     )
```

Or, better yet, but unique indexes on the fields that you don't want duplicated in the table:

```
create unique index idx_user_username on user(usr_name);
create unique index idx_user_email on usr(email);
```

Let the database protect the table.  It is there to help you.